# knownhosts file not generating when ssh keys are created

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

So when I generate my ssh keys, I see that other members of my team have known hosts in their .shh directory.  Am I missing a parameter?  What exactly does the file knownhosts do?  Do I need it?

Comment: It contains known hosts. You do not know any hosts until you actually _connect_ to one. Generating a SSH key does not create this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`known_hosts` has nothing to do with your ssh keys.

It's a file that is created/appended whenever you connect to a new host (ssh/git server) and said "yes" to the question if you trust the host and want to continue connecting.

The file will contain the signatures of those hosts, so that ssh can automatically re-check when connecting to a host, if you've already confirmed trusting that host.